# Ansible - Looping and Debug/Register

Tags: ansible

I have the following task.
However, it doesn't output the output for each ping that is produced, and I only get a 1 x output. When there should be x 5.

**Task**

```
  tasks:
    - name: "Check Connectivity (ping)"
      nxos_ping:
        provider: "{{ nxos_ssh }}"
        source: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['lo0_ipaddr'] }}"
        vrf: default
        dest: "192.168.1.{{item}}"
      with_sequence: start=1 end=5
      register: out

    - debug:
        msg:
         - "command: {{ out['results'][0]['commands'][0] }}"
```

**Example**

```
TASK [Check Connectivity (ping)] ***************************************************************************************************
ok: [spine-nxos-1] => (item=1)
ok: [spine-nxos-2] => (item=1)
ok: [spine-nxos-2] => (item=2)
ok: [spine-nxos-1] => (item=2)
ok: [spine-nxos-1] => (item=3)
ok: [spine-nxos-2] => (item=3)
ok: [spine-nxos-1] => (item=4)
ok: [spine-nxos-2] => (item=4)
ok: [spine-nxos-1] => (item=5)
ok: [spine-nxos-2] => (item=5)

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [spine-nxos-1] => {
    "msg": [
        "command: ping 192.168.1.1 count 5 source 192.168.1.1 vrf default"
    ]
}
ok: [spine-nxos-2] => {
    "msg": [
        "command: ping 192.168.1.1 count 5 source 192.168.1.2 vrf default"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working correct, as you only print out the first element of the registered output. If you want to see all your commands you should replace the last line of your playbook with:

```
- "command {{ out | json_query('results[*].commands[*]') }}"
```

or loop through your output corresponding to your sequence:

```
debug:
  msg:
    - "command {{ out.results[item|int].commands[0]}}"
with_sequence: start=0 end=2
```